# $ [[n,1,d]] $ codes with $ n $ even

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

All the interesting/well-known $ [[n,1,d]] $ codes I know have $ n $ odd. Moreover, all these codes have the property that $ X^{\otimes n} $ implements logical $ X $ and $ Z^{\otimes n} $ implements logical $ Z $ (this property of course implies that $ n $ is odd since logical $ X $ and logical $ Z $ must anticommute).

Are there any interesting/well-known $ [[n,1,d]] $ codes for $ n $ even? If so what are logical $ X $ and logical $ Z $ for those codes?

Note: I don't consider the $ [[4,1,2]] $ code given by adding another stabilizer like $ ZZII $ to $ <XXXX,ZZZZ> $ to be an interesting code.

Comment: what about the Toric code?

Comment: toric code has k=2

Comment: @DaftWullie I guess by Toric code you mean some kind of $ [[n,1,d]] $ surface code?

Comment: look here http://www.codetables.de/ for many examples, For example $[[6,1,3]]$, $[[8,1,3]]$,...

Comment: @unknown ok this is a very cool reference. I'm happy with the $ [[24,1,8]] $ code given there as an answer. Interesting to note that for every even number less than 24 the $ [[n,1,d]] $ code in the table is explicitly described as  either an extension of a well known $ [[n,1,d]] $ code for $ n $ odd or as a restriction of a well known $ [[n,2,d]] $ code for $ n $ even. Anyway I would definitely consider that $ [[24,1,8]] $ code as an example of an $ [[n,1,d]] $ code of independent interest. Now I'm just curious what the logical $ X $ and logical $ Z $ are for that code?

Comment: Found this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.00197 which discusses an infinite family of $ [[4L^2,1,2L]] $ codes with interesting properties. They might just be some sort of surface code? not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the $[[24,1,8]]$ code and its logicals :

stabilizers : [

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

logicals: [

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]]
```

I checked that its distance is 8.

Comment: Interesting, it seems that $ Z^{\otimes 24} $ and $ X^{\otimes 24} $ both commute with the stabilizer so they both implement logical operations. I'm guessing neither of them are in the stabilizer in which case they would be implementing nontrivial logical operations.  Since logical $ X $ and logical $ Z $ anticommute it can't both be the case that $ Z^{\otimes 24} $ implements logical $ Z $ and $ X^{\otimes 24} $ implemenets logical $ X $. I wonder what logical operations they actually implement(or maybe they are in the stabilizer and I just can't see it)?

Comment: Try adding the last 4 stabilizers together (found by using mathematica. I set the stabilizer matrix above to a variable `code` and executed `LinearSolve[Transpose[code], Join[Table[0, {24}], Table[1, {24}]], 
 Modulus -> 2]`